# How to modify/organize data on a file with Awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this

```
ADRESSE_1,ADRESSE_SUITE,CODE
1 boulevard Veyrier Montagnères,,33120
2, rue du Débarcadère,33120
6 bis avenue du Général de Gaulle,,44180
avenue du Parc Pereire,,93250
```

On three lines, I summarize a file that contains several hundred lines.

I would like to clean and then edit this file so it looks like this

```
NUMERO,ADRESSE_1,ADRESSE_SUITE,CODE
1,boulevard Veyrier Montagnères,,33120
2,rue du Débarcadère,,33120
6 bis,avenue du Général de Gaulle,,44180
,avenue du Parc Pereire,,93250
```

The lines vary from 16 to 17 columns, I can already adjust this with this script using printf to format

```
BEGIN { 
    FS = "[,]"; 
    OFS = ","; 
}
    NF != 16  {printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n"), $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17}
```

Comment: To fix the above you will need to define some rules on how to interpret ambiguous data.

Comment: Is a solution with sed fits your need or it must be done only with AWK?

Comment: I agree with Stephen's comment. E.g: how will you know what is part of the numbering (6 bis) from the street name? there could also be 8 ter, 99 quater, 36A, 49 Escalier C, and so on. Perhaps you have to do some statistics before starting the processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just put my solution with `sed` even it's asked especially for AWK, I find this solution more compact and direct:

GNU Sed (tested under CentOS):

```
sed -n '1!p' addresses.csv | sed -r 's!^([0-9]*(\sbis|\ster)?),?(.*)$!\1,\3!g;s!(.*)([^,])(,[0-9]*)$!\1\2,\3!g'
```

OS-X / BSD Sed

```
sed -n '1!p' addresses.csv | sed -E 's!^([0-9]*( bis| ter)?),?(.*)$!\1,\3!g;s!(.*)([^,])(,[0-9]*)$!\1\2,\3!g'
```

The first sed command is to take all lines except the 1st one (header).

For the second `sed` I use substitutions:

```
^                : Starting text.
[0-9]*           : all numbers (0, 1, ... 99, 999, 99999999 and so on) 
( bis| ter)?     : optionally followed by " bis" or " ter" (notice the space before); group 2
,?           : optionally followed by a comma
(.*)$            : the rest of the string until the end ($) (group 3)

!\1,\3           : replaced by first group (number + extension) - comma - third group
```

Note the second group is the parenthesis for ' bis' and ' ter', and the first group is this `([0-9]*( bis| ter){0,1})`

The second substitution is to normalize the commas (if it does not finished by `,,\d` we add an extra comma.

Comment: It works well, can you explain the end of the script please? `{0,1}),{0,1}(.*)$!\1,\3!`

Comment: The second line has only 3 columns

Comment: For the second line, it doesn't matter for my solution as I don't separates by columns. The only thing is it isolates the numbers + extension (bis, ter etc..) from the rest, the rest is my third group which will be taken "as-is"

Comment: it is this `{0,1}` that i don't understand

Comment: It's a standard Regex, it means 0 to 1 time. E.g `,{0,1}` means 0 or 1 comma (optionally).

Comment: I did not catch immediately your second comment, I saw after I missed a replacement of a comma. I updated my answer and added the GNU sed as well.

Comment: and `{0,1}` can also be replaced by `?`, it is just more visible what's doing.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it, I'm reading on __sed__ to be a little more comfortable on its use.
 I'm in question by the __`!`__ symbol?  I saw that you had updated your answer

Comment: The `!` symbol is the one I like to use but in fact you can replace it by something else ( `/` or `#` for example)

Comment: I recommend reading [this](http://blog.pierreroudier.net/2014/03/using-a-different-separator-than-with-sed/) about the separator... I have to habit not to use `/` because I have often URL's to parse.

Comment: it begins to be more clear

Comment: I can't understand the delimitation of the columns with sed `/^([0-9]*(\sbis|\ster)?),?(.*)$/` As with awk: `$1,$2`. I mean, where is the reference to the column

Answer (score 1):

@ruffp's comment is spot on. However, modulo that problem you could say:

```
awk -F, '!$2 { sub(/^([0-9]*)/, "&,"); sub(/,,/, ","); } 1'  addresses
```

Comment: This works very well, I completed it like this `awk -F, '!$2 { sub(/^([0-9]* (bis|ter)?)/, "&,"); sub(/,,/, ","); }1' list_resto.csv | awk -F, '{ sub(/ /, "");  }1'` - The result I want is approaching but remains uncertain

Comment: By putting this on a awk script file `NF != 2  { sub(/^([0-9]*)/, "&,"); sub(/,,/, ","); sub(/^[ \t]? /, "", $2); print $0; }` works like i want. But not in command line